# What statistical test to compare reader binary classification metrics with and without aid?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, binary-data, confusion-matrix

I have a dataset of MR images of **50 patients** with either benign or malignant liver lesions.
I asked **3 readers** to read the dataset and tell for each case if they thought it was benign or malignant.
Two weeks later, I asked the **same 3 readers** to read again the **same dataset** and to answer the same binary question but with the help of the predictions (benign/malignant) of a computer-aided diagnosis (CAD) system.

From these **binary classifications tasks**, I computed the sensitivity, specificity, and other classification metrics for each reader for the **unaided task** and the **aided task**.

I want to compare the metrics with and without the CAD system to know if the latter really helps or not (statistically speaking). I would like to compute it for each reader separately, but also for the readers grouped altogether.

1. What is the most appropriate statistical test in these precise conditions? Paired t-test (but non-independent observations)? McNemar test? Other?
2. Is it possible to add the confusion matrices of the three readers to calculate the group's metrics?
3. Is it possible to compute the 95% confidence interval for each reader's metric / for the group (bootstrap resampling?)?

Thank you for your help.
Best regards